# Can't convert excel cell to "hh:mm"

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem with converting cell value to `hh:mm` format.

Here is my code:

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

sql = "INSERT INTO temp (colId,rowId,kodp,data) "
plansql = "INSERT INTO tempPlan (colId,rowId,kodp,data) "
sql3 = "DELETE From temp"
sql4 = "DELETE From tempPlan"
conn.Execute sql3
conn.Execute sql4
For i = 13 To lastRow
    kodp = Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 1)
    For j = 6 To lastColumn
        data = Worksheets(2).Cells(11, j)
        sql = sql & "SELECT " & j & "," & i & "," & kodp & ",'" & data & "' UNION ALL "
    Next
    i = i + 10
Next
For i = 12 To lastRow
    kodp = Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 1)
    For j = 6 To lastColumn
        data = Worksheets(2).Cells(11, j)
        plansql = plansql & "SELECT " & j & "," & i & "," & kodp & ",'" & data & "' UNION ALL "
        'sql = sql & "SELECT " & j & "," & i & "," & kodp & ",'" & data & "' UNION ALL "
    Next
    i = i + 10
Next
sql = Left(sql, Len(sql) - 10)
plansql = Left(plansql, Len(plansql) - 10)
conn.Execute sql
conn.Execute plansql
sql2 = "SELECT t.rowId,t.ColID,Realization From FRM_Raport f INNER JOIN temp t ON f.EmployeeId=t.kodp and f.data=t.data"
sql5 = "SELECT t.rowId,t.colId,[Plan] From FRM_Raport f INNER JOIN tempPlan t ON f.Employeeid=t.kodp and f.data=t.data"
Set tmp = conn.Execute(sql2)

Do Until tmp.EOF
    For Each fld In tmp.Fields
        Worksheets(2).Cells(tmp.Fields(0), tmp.Fields(1)) = tmp.Fields(2)
    Next fld
    tmp.MoveNext
Loop

tmp.Close
Set tmp = Nothing

Set planRecordset = conn.Execute(sql5)



Do Until planRecordset.EOF
    For Each fld In planRecordset.Fields
        Worksheets(2).Cells(planRecordset.Fields(0), planRecordset.Fields(1)) = planRecordset.Fields(2)
    Next fld
    planRecordset.MoveNext
Loop

planRecordset.Close
Set planRecordset = Nothing
```

I need to convert Worksheets(2).Cells(i,j) (i=12 to lastRow,j=6 to lastColumn and i=13 to lastRow,j=6 to lastColumn) value into "hh:mm" format. I've tried to read datatype and it's Range or Empty. I also tried convert those cells into int first and it didn't work too. Any ideas ?

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Error message? Nothing happened? The numbers turned pink? Nuclear holocaust?

Comment: Also, you need to read (how to create minimal, complete and verifiable example)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]. YOu can't expect us to dig through all your code to find the error. Please just show the part with the error.

Answer (score 0):

give conditions here....
and then give,
Worksheets(2).Cells(i,j)  =  Format(THE_DATE_VARIABLE, "hh:mm")

Try this.

Comment: It converts entire row into "00:00"